# When changing woocommerce title hook the first item doesn't change

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a strange behaviour that I don't understand

I've changed the woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title hook to add a link to the title of the product. This is my code inside functions.php

```
// Add HREF TO TITLE
function abChangeProductsTitleHook(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
    add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'abChangeProductsTitle', 10 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'abChangeProductsTitleHook' );
function abChangeProductsTitle() {
    echo '<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product_title"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2>';
}
```

It works perfectly on all the products except the first one.

I've also made a similar change to another hook to change the thumbnail image to a background image and also this one doesn't work on the first product. It's always the first product even if I change the order of the products.

Below you see a screenshot of the the first row of products on the page and that the first one is displayed differently

[image: First product is different]

It would be really helpful if anyone knows that problem or can point me in the right direction .

Thank you very much
Alex

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way you are removing and adding the `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` is the problem. Try it this way.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'abChangeProductsTitle', 10 );
function abChangeProductsTitle() {
    echo '<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product_title"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2>';
}
```

Comment: I hope you understand what the problem was :)

Comment: I guess I know that it was but now I can look it up to know it exactly :) thanks

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: You've removed the filter so any plugins using it break.

Answer (score 1):

Although the accepted answer works, but why do we have to `remove` the title and then `add` it back in again? We could simply `filter` it in the first place.

```php
add_filter('the_title', 'your_shop_custom_title', 20, 2);

function your_shop_custom_title($the_title, $id)
{

  if (is_shop() && get_post_type($id) == 'product') : // runs only on the shop page

    $the_title = '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . $the_title . '</a>';

  endif;

  return $the_title;
}
```