# How can I change the product <h2> in Woocommerce Storefront to <h3>?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using a child theme to Woocommerce's Storefront theme. On the home page, it is rendering the product names of the featured products as h2s. I would like to change these to h3s (SEO reasons).

The h2s use this class: woocommerce-loop-product__title. I searched through the Storefront theme, and the only place I found that class was in CSS.

I looked in this file: /storefront/inc/storefront-template-functions.php and found this code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'storefront_featured_products' ) ) {
/**
 * Display Featured Products
 * Hooked into the `homepage` action in the homepage template
 *
 * @since  1.0.0
 * @param array $args the product section args.
 * @return void
 */
function storefront_featured_products( $args ) {

    if ( storefront_is_woocommerce_activated() ) {

        $args = apply_filters( 'storefront_featured_products_args', array(
            'limit'      => 4,
            'columns'    => 4,
            'orderby'    => 'date',
            'order'      => 'desc',
            'visibility' => 'featured',
            'title'      => __( 'We Recommend', 'storefront' ),
        ) );

        $shortcode_content = storefront_do_shortcode( 'products', apply_filters( 'storefront_featured_products_shortcode_args', array(
            'per_page'   => intval( $args['limit'] ),
            'columns'    => intval( $args['columns'] ),
            'orderby'    => esc_attr( $args['orderby'] ),
            'order'      => esc_attr( $args['order'] ),
            'visibility' => esc_attr( $args['visibility'] ),
        ) ) );

        /**
         * Only display the section if the shortcode returns products
         */
        if ( false !== strpos( $shortcode_content, 'product' ) ) {

            echo '<section class="storefront-product-section storefront-featured-products" aria-label="' . esc_attr__( 'Featured Products', 'storefront' ) . '">';

            do_action( 'storefront_homepage_before_featured_products' );

            echo '<h2 class="section-title">' . wp_kses_post( $args['title'] ) . '</h2>';

            do_action( 'storefront_homepage_after_featured_products_title' );

            echo $shortcode_content;

            do_action( 'storefront_homepage_after_featured_products' );

            echo '</section>';

        }
    }
}
```

}

I think this runs the Featured Products section.

I tried changing this code:

```
echo '<h2 class="section-title">' . wp_kses_post( $args['title'] ) . '</h2>';
```

to:

```
echo '<h3 class="section-title">' . wp_kses_post( $args['title'] ) . '</h3>';
```

I uploaded the /inc/ folder to my child directory, and there were no changes. I tried uploaded the storefront-template-functions.php file into the /inc/ file of the original storefront theme. Again, nothing happened.

I'm stumped. I really thought I had the correct bit of code to change these to h3s. Any idea what I need to do to change the Featured Product h2s into h3s?

Comment: Are you sure it is not changed? There are two possibilities. Either you edited the wrong part of the code (There are probably some other code to produce the h2) or it was actually changed, but some css made h3 looks like h2. You can right click and `view source code` to make sure.

Comment: I did use the browser's inspect function to confirm they are still rendering as h2s

Comment: Just a bit note: In case of you have a JavaScript that change some HTML tags, `browser's inspect element` will not show you the original tags. That's why I suggest `view source`. However, I'm glad you've find the solution by yourself :)

Comment: @goFrendiAsgard - Thanks for the tip. I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, it turns out that I was looking in the wrong place and doing the wrong thing. I needed to add something to the functions.php file in my child theme to get this to work. Here's what I added:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'abChangeProductsTitle', 10 );
function abChangeProductsTitle() {
echo '<h3 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">' . get_the_title() . '</h3>';
}
```

I got the basis for this code from this answer:
[When changing woocommerce title hook the first item doesn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46174640/when-changing-woocommerce-title-hook-the-first-item-doesnt-change)

Comment: great but be carefull the class of html,

not "woocommerce-loop-product_title" but "woocommerce-loop-product__title"

Comment: @WebMat Good catch. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a number of things. First thing that came to mind is a page caching system that is rendering cached web pages. So if a system like that is in place disable it. Then try and view the page with a force fresh by clicking CTRL+F5.

If that doesn't work next thing could be that in the CSS h2 and h3 tags have the same values. Check your CSS and see if there is a h1, h2, h3, h4 declaration and see if it has been declared as a group. If it is remove the h3 and style it to your needs.

Comment: It is still rendering as h2s. I checked the source code. I have no caching plugins in Wordpress. I just tried clearing my cache  and it is still rendering as h2s.

Comment: Ah, I see what that change did. It changed the featured section's h2 to a h3. So, I guess I need to hunt some more for the right code...

Comment: Okay so if the element did get changed to h3 and it's not making a difference then I definitely think that your CSS file has your h*s all grouped. :)