# Woocommerce hook - all cart items behave correctly except the first item

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add **first paragraph** of **the content**, below product name in the Woocommerce Cart page. All items display first paragraph only, except the first product in the cart list (that's the problem).

I used this code to add a function to woocommerce_after_cart_item_name hook:

```
// Add a SUBTITLE to the cart items below product title
add_action('woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', 'add_custom_subtitle_after_cart_item_name', 0, 1);
function add_custom_subtitle_after_cart_item_name($cart_item)
{
    //Get the product content and then extract the first paragraph
    $content = get_post($cart_item['product_id'])->post_content;

    $filtered_content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

    $filtered_content = explode('</p>', $filtered_content);
    $filtered_content = array_slice($filtered_content, 0,  1);
    $filtered_content = implode('</p>',  $filtered_content);

    if ($filtered_content) {
        echo '<div class="custom-woo-cart__item-subtitle">' . $filtered_content . '</div>';
    }
}
```

The code above result:

[image]

### [image]

### Expected behaviour:

I want all cart items in the Cart page to display only first paragraph of that product's content, below their title.

### Problem:

All cart items in the Cart page displays that correctly, except the first item.

---

### Further information:

I tried to do this with a sample text and when I use the code above without the `apply_filters('the_content', $content)` part, the problem is fixed:

```
// Add a custom text to the cart items below product title
add_action('woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', 'add_custom_subtitle_after_cart_item_name', 0, 1);
function add_custom_subtitle_after_cart_item_name($cart_item)
{
    //Custom text instead of actual content of the products
    $content = 'Paragraph 1 <br> Paragraph 2 <br> Paragraph 3 ';

    $filtered_content = explode('<br>', $content);
    $filtered_content = array_slice($filtered_content, 0,  1);
    $filtered_content = implode('<br>',  $filtered_content);

    //Display the first paragraph of the text
    if ($filtered_content) {
        echo '<div class="custom-woo-cart__item-subtitle woo-font-color-gray">' . $filtered_content . '</div>';
    }

}
```

[image]

So I wonder if the problem is somehow related to this line (The second block of code which works correctly, lacks this line):

```
    $filtered_content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

Whatever it is, it seems the first item is not completely included in the operations of my code and somehow gets escaped.

---

**EDIT:** Seems Woocommerce has a habit of making problems with the first items:
[When changing woocommerce title hook the first item doesn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46174640/when-changing-woocommerce-title-hook-the-first-item-doesnt-change)

---

**EDIT2:** Following CBroe's helpful comment, I realised this line:

```
$filtered_content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

Adds `<p>...</p>` tag to every paragraph of the contents, which is correct and expected. Only, it doesn't do that for the first item. **Apparently has no impact on the first item at all, as I compared the generated html of the first item in the DOM with a tool (before and after that line).**

Therefore, with no `</p>` added to the first item's content, the next line:

```
$filtered_content = explode('</p>', $filtered_content);
```

Wouldn't have any impact on it and couldn't split its paragraphs. I don't know why that line doesn't add `<p>...</p>` tags to the first item.

---

**Edit3: Changing themes shows no difference.**

I changed the theme to some default themes (twentynineteen and twentytwentytwo themes) and then added Woocommerce support and also added the code of `add_custom_subtitle_after_cart_item_name` in the fuctions.php of that theme. Same result. The problem persists. First item in the cart list keeps showing all of the content below its title (instead of showing only first paragraph).

---

PS I don't want to use Woocommerce template override and edit the template for this, if possible. I'd like to use hooks to fulfil my goal. Also curious to know what's the problem with my code anyway.

Comment: How about you start by checking what the result of `$filtered_content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);` actually _is_ for the first product then?

Comment: Thanks. I added the EDIT2 part. Please read that.

Comment: Maybe your theme is giving the first post special treatment, to show it more prominently, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks. It was not the case, as I tested other themes out. More info added on the EDIT3 section in this question.

Comment: If applying the `the_content` filter "breaks" this, then probably something has added a callback function to this, that makes it return a different HTML structure for the first post.

Comment: @CBroe Removing the `$filtered_content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);` and then changing the explode function to `explode(PHP_EOL, $content)` fixed the problem. So this function will separate the content by `line breaks` rather than by `</p>`s. As stupid as that. I don't know if it's a good practice so will wait for possible better answers and also an explanation to the problem: **What's the deal with the first cart item?**
Thanks for the insightful comments.

Comment: The filter might do more than just make line breaks into paragraphs, _much_ more if any plugins add their own functionality via that. So you might be losing functionality, if you simply don't apply the filter any more.